# How to combine multiple Observable type arrays Observable<T[]>?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running multiple queries on Firebase Firestore. They all (can) return an Observable. I would like to combine all Observable into ONE Observable.

I have tried different RxJS operators, like; combineLatest, forkJoin, concat, zip, merge and mergeMap. But I have not been able to achieve the desired result.

```
getPrivateBooksFromAuthors(authors): Observable<Book[]> {
    let bookRefs: Observable<Book[]>[] = [];
    authors.map(key => {
      bookRefs.push(this.afs.collection<Book>('books', ref => 
        ref.where('public', '==', false)
           .where('authors', 'array-contains', key)
        ).valueChanges())
    });
    return bookRefs[0]
}
```

In the above piece of code I get all the private books from authors[0]. When I return concat(...bookRefs) or concat(bookRefs[0], bookRefs[1]), I still only get the books from authors[0]. I expect to get all the books from all the authors provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Doflamingo said, you can use **forkJoin** in order to call them in parallel and receive a response with an array of all responses resolved.
The problem you have is that every response is a Book[], so in the forkJoin you receive an array of Book[] (Book[][]). You need to **flat** the Book[][] into a Book[]. You can do it using the a map an a **reduce function**.

Here I posted a simple code snipped that console logs the response of the forkJoin and the result after applying the reduce function.

```js
function mockBooks$(key): Observable<Book[]> {
  return rxjs.of([key + '-book1', key + '-book2', key + '-book3']);
}

function getPrivateBooksFromAuthors(authors): Observable<Book[]> {
    let bookRefs: Observable<Book[]>[] = authors.map(key => mockBooks$(key));

    return rxjs.forkJoin(bookRefs).pipe(
        rxjs.operators.tap((books) => console.log('After forkJoin', books)),
        // You need this flattening operation!!
        rxjs.operators.map(books => books.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur], []) ));
}


const authors = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'];
getPrivateBooksFromAuthors(authors).subscribe((data) => console.log('Final result', data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Llorenç, thank you for your answer!! The code sample helped a lot! When I ran your code, it worked great. As soon as I replaced the mockBooks with my real call to my Firestore collection, it failed. It took me a couple more days to figure it out. But I think it fails if some authors have no books in the database. Exchanging forkJoin with combineLatest fixed it for me. But I really needed your map and reduce code!! Thank you!

Comment: I am glad it helped! forkJoin maybe don't work for you because your observable .valueChanges() may never complete. In order to complete you can return: .valueChanges.pipe(take(1)). Or use CombineLatest like: combineLatest(bookRefs).pipe(take(1)). Note: if you don't put the take(1), you should unsubscribe later. If what you want is keep subscribed, you can just remove the take(1) an listen for every change.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is use [fork join](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61).

`Fork` let you to execute the call in parallel. The result of every call it's put in one object (`join`) and you can get the all call's result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I do return forkJoin(bookRefs) at the end of the function, I get a type error. forkJoin returns an Observable<Book[][]>. So an observable book array array. Instead of combining the arrays to one array. Or am I implementing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

@Doflamingo pointed us in the direction of forkJoin and @Llorenç gave a great code example with the map and reduce pipes to combine the Observables into one Observable. For me, the forkJoin failed if some authors didn't have Books. So I ended up going with combineLatest (which doesn't wait for all the Observables to be completed). This is my final code (all the credit goes to @Llorenç):

```
  mockBooks$(key): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<Book>('books', ref => 
      ref.where('private', '==', true)
         .where('authors', 'array-contains', key)
      ).valueChanges()
    // return of([key + '-book1', key + '-book2', key + '-book3']);
  }

  getPrivateBooksFromAuthors(authors): Observable<Book[]> {
    let bookRefs: Observable<Book[]>[] = authors.map(key => this.mockBooks$(key));

     // return combineLatest(bookRefs).pipe(
     //     tap((books) => console.log('After forkJoin', books)),
     //     // You need this flattening operation!!
     //     map(books => books.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur], []) ));

     return combineLatest<Book[]>(bookRefs).pipe(
        map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur) ) ),
     )
  }
```

I've commented out Llorenç's code, to show the difference. Thank you to both of you!